# Fixtures in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bdd, fixtures

I'm new to using RSpec for writing tests in a Rails application which uses a MySQL database. I have defined my fixtures and am loading them in my spec as follows:

```
before(:all) do
  fixtures :student
end
```

Does this declaration save the data defined in my fixtures in the students table or does it just load the data in the table while the tests are running and remove it from the table after all the tests are run?

Comment: Instead of fixtures, give [factory_girl](http://www.fabricationgem.org/) or [fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org/) a try.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to use fixtures with RSpec, specify your fixtures in the describe block, not within a before block:

```
describe StudentsController do
  fixtures :students

  before do
    # more test setup
  end
end
```

Your student fixtures will get loaded into the students table and then rolled back at the end of each test using database transactions.

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/model-specs/transactional-examples#run-in-transactions-with-fixture

Answer (score 9):

First of all: You cannot use method `fixtures` in `:all` / `:context` / `:suite hook`. Do not try to use fixtures in these hooks (like `post(:my_post)`).

You can prepare fixtures only in describe/context block as Infuse write earlier.

Call

```
fixtures :students, :teachers
```

do not load any data into DB! Just prepares helper methods `students` and `teachers`.
Demanded records are loaded lazily in the moment when You first try to access them. Right before

```
dan=students(:dan)
```

This will load students and teachers in `delete all from table + insert fixtures` way.

**So if you prepare some students in before(:context) hook, they will be gone now!!**

Insert of records is done just once in test suite.

Records from fixtures are not deleted at the end of test suite. They are deleted and re-inserted on next test suite run.

example:

```
 #students.yml
   dan:
     name: Dan 
   paul:
     name: Paul

 #teachers.yml
    snape:
      name: Severus




describe Student do
  fixtures :students, :teachers
  
  before(:context) do
    @james=Student.create!(name: "James")
  end

  it "have name" do
   expect(Student.find(@james.id)).to be_present
   expect(Student.count).to eq 1
   expect(Teacher.count).to eq 0
  
   students(:dan)
   
   expect(Student.find_by_name(@james.name)).to be_blank
   expect(Student.count).to eq 2
   expect(Teacher.count).to eq 1
   
  end
end


#but when fixtures are in DB (after first call), all works as expected (by me)

describe Teacher do
  fixtures :teachers # was loaded in previous tests
  
  before(:context) do
    @james=Student.create!(name: "James")
    @thomas=Teacher.create!(name: "Thomas")
  end

  it "have name" do
   expect(Teacher.find(@thomas.id)).to be_present
   expect(Student.count).to eq 3 # :dan, :paul, @james
   expect(Teacher.count).to eq 2 # :snape, @thomas
  
   students(:dan)
      
   expect(Teacher.find_by_name(@thomas.name)).to be_present
   expect(Student.count).to eq 3
   expect(Teacher.count).to eq 2
   
  end
end
```

**All expectations in tests above will pass**

If these test are run again (in next suite) and in this order, than expectation

```
 expect(Student.count).to eq 1
```

**will be NOT met!** There will be 3 students (:dan, :paul and fresh new @james). All of them will be deleted before `students(:dan)` and only :paul and :dan will be inserted again.

Comment: Yeah! I found the trick to make all fixtures to be loaded before all tests. Just add RSpec.configure { |config| config.global_fixtures= :all }  AND test in spec_helper directly, which will try to access any fixture. This way all fixtures are loaded in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`before(:all)` keeps the exact data around, as it's loaded/created once.  You do your thing, and at the end of the test it stays.  That's why bui's link has `after(:all)` to destroy or use `before(:each); @var.reload!;end` to get the latest data from the tests before. I can see using this approach in nested rspec describe blocks.